# Peewee: how to make a query with a set of tuple?

Tags: python, peewee

My SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE Message (
    message_id varchar(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    channel_id integer NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
)
```

I have a set of tuple, the first item is a user_id field and the second is a channel_id field. Example of set:

```
user_channel_set = {(156, 23), (235, 15), (156, 15)}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this but with only one query.

```
for t in user_channel_set:
    Message.select().where((Message.user_id == t[0]) & (Message.channel_id == t[1]))
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the '==' with 'in'

Comment: First off please be sure to use parens around both "x == y" expressions, since python's operator precedence may be causing your query to come out malformed (due to the precedence of bitwise-and "&").

Comment: I edited, it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question. You can try using a VALUES statement and a common-table expression.

```
val_list = ValuesList(list(user_channel_set)).cte('vals', columns=['uid', 'cid'])
query = (Message
         .select()
         .join(val_list, on=(
             (Message.user_id == val_list.c.uid) &
             (Message.channel_id == val_list.c.cid)))
         .with_cte(val_list))
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, I would like to know if is possible to get only the last message for all tuple user/channel with the query. Like if I add .order_by(Message.timestamp.desc()).get() in the query of my example

Comment: For that you probably want window functions.

Comment: I changed my SQLite database to Mysql and It doesn't work with Mysql (Version 8.0.19): SQL syntax error

Comment: according to https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/ MySQL added CTE feature since 8.0

Comment: and the problem is in MySQL VALUES must be with keyword Row, but the ValuesList in Peewee has no 'Row' keyword